# Almacenar teclas del teclado en una variable javascript

Tags: javascript, web

Lo que quiero hacer es almacenar determinadas teclas del teclado en un array para después hacer lo siguiente.

```js
const letrasDelTeclado = ['tecla1','tecla2','tecla3','tecla4']

letrasDelTeclado.forEach(tecla =>{
  tecla.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
     console.log(e.key)
  })
})
```

El problema: no se como almacenar las teclas en 'letrasDelTeclado', ya que lo que hay en el codigo de arriba son strings sin mas.

El objetivo final es asociar un event listener por cada tecla dentro de 'letrasDelTeclado'.

No me sirve esto, que ya lo he probado:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  
    switch (e.key){
    case 'a':
    
    break;
 
    case 'b':
     
    break;
 
    case 'c': 
    
   break;
    
    case 'd':  
    
   break;
 
    } 
 })
```

Necesito tener un event listener por tecla para que lo que quiero hacer funcione. Alguna idea?

Comment: porque necesitas un evenlistener por cada tecla? no seria mejor un evento change en un input y que dependiendo la tecla tenga un comportamiento/flujo diferente?

Comment: necesito un eventListener por tecla ya que esas mismas teclas han de ser presionadas simultáneamente. (las teclas son los controles de un juego ,w,a,s,d,) He probado infinidad de veces a hacerlo con un mismo event listener pero al pulsar dos teclas diferentes se cancela constantemente y es imposible.

Comment: Te serviria entonces tener dos eventos un keyup y key down para detectar cuando la tecla empieza a ser y pulsada y cuando es liberada para saber cuanto dura el  desplazamiento del objeto dentro del juego?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo práctico sobre como podrías hacer lo que creo que intentas hacer:

```js
(function() {  
  // define las teclas que quieres detectar,
  // true significa que la tecla esta siendo presionada, false lo contrario
  var keys = {
    A: false,
    W: false,
    S: false,
    D: false,
  };
  
  // handler para los eventos del teclado:
  function handleKeyEvent(isPressed, e) {
    // obten la tecla presionada:
    var key = e.key.toUpperCase();

    // si la tecla es alguna de las teclas definidas en el objeto "keys"
    // actualice el estado de la tecla:
    // si es "keydown": isPressed = true // tecla presionada
    // si es "keyup": isPressed = false  // tecla soltada
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(keys, key)) {
      keys[key] = isPressed;
    }
  }
  
  // registra los eventos keydown y keyup para determinar cuando
  // una tecla es presionada y cuando es soltada:
  window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyEvent.bind(null, true));
  window.addEventListener('keyup', handleKeyEvent.bind(null, false));
  
  // esto es solo un ejemplo donde muevo el párrafo cada vez que
  // presiono las teclas:
  var currentX = 0;
  var currentY = 0;
  var paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

  function moveObject() {
    if (keys.W) currentY -= 1;
    if (keys.A) currentX -= 2;
    if (keys.S) currentY += 1;
    if (keys.D) currentX += 2;
    
    paragraph.style = 'transform: translate(' + currentX + 'px, ' + currentY + 'px);';
  }

  // este es un ciclo infinito controlado que valida el estado de las teclas
  // y las acciones a realizar:
  function run() {
    moveObject();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
  }
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(run);
})();
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.frame {
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  user-select: none;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: .3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <p>Move me with W, A, S, D.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira a ver si te sirve así:

```
var tecla=[]; //el array de teclas

window.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
    tecla[e.code]=true;
});

window.addEventListener("keyup",(e)=>{
    tecla[e.code]=false;
});
```

y luego, para leer las teclas:

```
if(tecla["KeyW"]){console.log("Has pulsado la tecla W");}
if(tecla["KeyA"]){console.log("Has pulsado la tecla A");}
```